# Good way to share demo code in Visual Studio without it depending on the version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

Many of my colleagues use Visual Studio 2010 and 2008, I use 2010, 2012 and 2008.

Has anyone found a good way to share assemblies and source code without having the reader having to convert the solution to whatever flavour of Visual Studio they are using?

(I realise that frameworks need to be installed etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple solutions for each per "Visual studio version". but make sure you have compatible target framework version in your projects.

Comment: That was what I was thinking, have `MyDemo_2008.sln`, `MyDemo_2010.sln`, `MyDemo_2012,sln` and maybe soon `MyDemo_2013.sln`.  It's just not very *elegant* though.

Comment: I know 2012 can open a 2010 `.sln` without conversion (I do not know 100% sure about 2013 but I think it is the same).

Answer (score 2):

If you are only distributing a single project file you can just leave out the solution file (`.sln`) and only include the project (`.csproj`) files. Visual studio will create it's own `.sln` file the first time the user saves the project after opening it.

If you have multiple assemblies you need included one thing you can do is have multiple `.sln` files (one for 2008 and one for 2010 and newer. 2010, 2012, and 2013 can all use the same `.sln` file) and have them point at the same `.csproj` files. Just create the solution in 2008 with all of its projects, then create a new empty solution in 2010 and add all of the existing projects to the 2010 solution.

**EDIT:** I just found out that [some types of projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#sectionToggle0) are not cross version compatible. If you run in to this just create a version spcific `.csproj` file too and have it point at the same source files (you will need to keep the projects in sync by hand if you change project settings or add/remove any new source files)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's more than one proj.  Good spot on the incompatible proj files to.  I was considering providing them and letting the reading add them to their own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, program your solution to the lowest possible .NET framework version... Sounds like 2.0 would be right up your alley. Do this because the older versions of Visual Studio do not support the newer frameworks.

Comment: Possible 2005 use. ;)

Comment: Cheers, but its 4.0 + I'm afraid.

Comment: @BanksySan If you are 4.0+ then the projects will not be shareable with 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If your code can all be written using one of the Express versions, then you and your colleagues should all get VS2013 Express. All of the Express versions are free, so there's little reason not to use the latest.

Comment: Good idea, but I don't think I can get my company to install 2013 just so people can read my demo.  I don't think it'd be that higher priority.

Comment: I meant VS2013 Express, which is a free download.